# store SQL Scope Identity in a C# variable

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to extract the last insert auto generated RowID (or key) via an SQL command and store it as a C# variable.

I can do the first part but failing to do the 2nd part....

**Updated:-**

```
Int32 newRowID = 0;

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // SQL Query-1: to store validated information in the Enrollment table. //
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(xxx_DBConnect.SqlServerConnection);

    String strSQL = " OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY zzzzzzzKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE zzzzzzzCertificate1"
        + " INSERT INTO [xxx].[dbo].[yyy]"
        + " (Type, Name, DBA, Address1, City, State, Zip, TIN, TINLast4, NPI)"
        + " values (@Type, @Name, @DBA, @Address1, @rCity, @State, @Zip, ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('zzzzzzz'),CONVERT(VARCHAR, @TIN)), @TINLast4, @rNPI)"
        + " CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY zzzzzzzKey;"
        + " SET @RowId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

    // Connection is explicitly opened.
    Connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSQL, Connection);

    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "@RowId";
    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);


    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", _type);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", _Name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBA", _DBA);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", _address);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", _city);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", _state);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", _zip);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIN", _tIN);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TINLast4", _TINlast4);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NPI", _nPI);

    //newRowID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();// <--- how do I write this in the correct syntax ?? ....

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


    if (parameter.Value != DBNull.Value)
        {
            newRowID = (int)parameter.Value;
        }


    Connection.Close();
```

**I don't get an error, but newRowID = 0...where as the expected result is 130.... I am supposing the returned SQLparamater is returning a '0'**

Is there a correct way of writing the following syntax?

such that I can access the variable newRowID anywhere in my C# code and use it...

Comment: You say you're failing... what's happening? Is an exception being thrown? Are you getting an unexpected result?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Instead of `SET @RowId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` I would do `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();` no output params, and executeScalar should work with the select clause!

Comment: I get an error: "Specified cast is not valid." expected return of rowID = 139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to `declare @RowId int;`. Just change the last statement to `SELECT`:

```
 String strSQL = " OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY zzzzzzzKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE zzzzzzzCertificate1"
        + " INSERT INTO [xxx].[dbo].[yyy]"
        + " (Type, Name, DBA, Address1, City, State, Zip, TIN, TINLast4, NPI)"
        + " values (@Type, @Name, @DBA, @Address1, @rCity, @State, @Zip, ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('zzzzzzz'),CONVERT(VARCHAR, @TIN)), @TINLast4, @rNPI)"
        + " CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY zzzzzzzKey;"
        + " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
```

This will make `ExecuteScalar()` return value.

**UPDATE**:

To avoid cast errors (since SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns DECIMAL) you can cast it to `int` in both places.

Replace last select in the query above with

```
 SELECT CONVERT(int, SCOPE_IDENTITY());
```

and in your C# code use

```
int newRowID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Add the RowId as an Output parameter (Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

[Scope_Identity return decimal(38,0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

remove the `declare statement for @RowId` from your sql query.

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "@RowId";
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal; 
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

command.Parameters.Add(parameter);


command.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (parameter.Value!=DbNull.Value)
{
   newRowID = (Int32) parameter.Value;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you get the output values from sql parameters. They can have direction.

Comment: it complains about newRowID as being already declared and needs to be unique..."The variable name '@RowId' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

Comment: I personally like this solution because it means there is not a magic return result (magic being you have to read the SQL to understand what it's doing).  As an out parameter, you can define a nice variable name that explicitly informs other programmers what the value is.

Comment: thanks `Rene`, I updated my original question. I dont get any errors, but the returned value is '0' whereas I am expecting a 140.

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to pass an output parameter to the database like this

```
SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter();
sqlParameter.ParameterName = "@RowId";
sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
sqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

command.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
```

Then you need to remove this line from your sql

```
declare @RowId int;
```

and finally you can get the value like this after executing your query

```
if(sqlParameter.Value != DBNull.Value)
   newRowID  = (Int32)sqlParameter.Value;
```

**Edit:**

As the return type of paramter is not mentioned in the question  therefore i have used Int32 here. You can use your desired type.

Comment: it could be because type of Scope_Identity is bigint or other numeric datatype. can you try Convert.ToInt32(sqlParamter.Value) ?

Comment: @Philo It means that your RowId parameter is not a 32 bit integer. You need to specify the type here as well as sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int; like if it is decimal you need to change both of these as decimal

Comment: cool. no errors. type is int... but at the end of it all newRowID = 0.... whereas it should be 130 ...

Comment: Yes, but for curiosity's sake...I wanted to make this approach work as well.:)